# My clips never gets HD quality on Facebook

Tags: facebook, video-processing, adobe-premiere

I have a problem uploading videos to Facebook and keep the original quality. I have tried every step and various solutions but it still never get HD (1080p) quality as the source file are. The highest I get is 720p.

I have Premiere Pro CC, the lastest version, and I have tried almost every codec settings there is. My file is in good quality 1080x1080 and when I export it the video looks great on the computer and even on Youtube.

Unfortunately with Facebook I can't get it to Work on my customers Facebook Page and the material looks crap.

There are other firms also uploading videos to the pages and theire content gets HD quality.

I have tried:

Alomost every codec setting recomended out there with h264.

- I have checked the HD-box in Video Settings on my Facebook.
- I have tried export it in Apple ProRes HQ and uploaded 1-2 GB files.
- I have downloaded HD 1080p material from Youtube and uploaded to FB.
- I have tried upload directly and even schedule it for weeks later.

Unfortunately there is still no luck.

Anyone out there having a solution I should try?

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem for ages! and after a LOT of research, the only real answer I found is that Facebook gives different priorities to different users (ex: Verified and Not Verified).
So it has nothing to do with your rendering export settings...
It's all Facebook decisions...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may simply be a problem with the upload handling.  You should be fine utilizing the native Facebook codec though it never hurts to rebuild it. There's explicit steps you can take here regarding Facebook codec standards: https://blog.pond5.com/12628-social-media-export-settings-in-adobe-premiere-pro-the-ultimate-guide/

Here's a few things I recommend for troubleshooting:

- check that HD gear in the bottom right corner includes 1080. If it only goes up to 
  720, check to make sure your file is indeed 1080x1080.
- make sure you are the one uploading directly into your customer's Facebook page.
- after you've uploaded it, give it 10-20 minutes and check on it again. It's possible that they haven't finished converting the file to the proper quality if you immediately view it after upload.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The best answer you have to speak someone with Technical support and this is only possible if you publish this question everywhere over the internet because the regular support are trained only to send you useless articles.

Secondly Youtube is the king of HD and 4K videos so far. [Check out my 4K video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXxCo5P9b5I). When i try to upload this 4K video on my facebook page. They simple create error. Then i downgrade it to 1080p and after upload it only watchable in 720p. Since, facebook do not care about real creator they will never reply your comments on time so get some real one from linkedin or nudge again and again their support by calling and emailing them back to back so they force to add a real technical guy in your discussion and he will solve your issue on your facebook page.

Drop me your page link on my [Instagram Profile](https://www.instagram.com/its.alisyed/). i will add you in my discussion with facebook technical team.